# vercel read-only file system, chmod

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, vercel

**Hi everyone**,
I use vercel to deploy my project. One of my NextJS project dependencies, located inside node_modules, reads and writes files in its own folder. When I import this dependency, I get the following error:

```
"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"Error: EROFS: read-only file system, chmod '/var/task/node_modules/MY_DEPENDENCY/src/FILE'"
```

**Is there a solution?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not mention what the project dependency does, however its generally an anti-pattern to use serverless functions to write files as there is no guarantee of existence on the next invocation

*Potential directional Solves*

It might be better for you depending on the type of file written (assets or flat files ) to a bucket like S3 OR to a database - There are multiple ways to accomplish writing of *shared* state between functions.

Comment: Thank you for your help! My project dependency shares its logs and performance information in its files, and vercel does not allow me to change files because it is a kind of server simulation.

Answer (score 0):

Check out following thread - https://github.com/vercel/community/discussions/314?sort=new

If you need to store something temporarily, you may try to use `/tmp` directory.

Limit 512 MB + no guaranty - https://github.com/vercel/vercel/discussions/5320

Comment: I tried the /tmp directory, it's cleaned at the end of the request